# Rotación de proxies en Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

estoy buscando una manera de que cuando mi `selenium chrome driver` se cierre se coloque otro proxy de un documento o de una pagina web, preferiría documento, pero no se como hacer para que una vez utilizado un proxy, lo descarte y se pase al siguiente. Lo único que encontré fue un script que cuando inserto mi código me da error en la parte de `co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`, si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaría agradecido. Os dejo el código que encontré de [tushortz en github](https://gist.github.com/tushortz):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

import time


co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_argument("log-level=3")
co.add_argument("--headless")

def get_proxies(co=co):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=co)
    driver.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")

    PROXIES = []
    proxies = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[role='row']")
    for p in proxies:
        result = p.text.split(" ")

        if result[-1] == "yes":
            PROXIES.append(result[0]+":"+result[1])

    driver.close()
    return PROXIES


ALL_PROXIES = get_proxies()


def proxy_driver(PROXIES, co=co):
    prox = Proxy()

    if PROXIES:
        pxy = PROXIES[-1]
    else:
        print("--- Proxies used up (%s)" % len(PROXIES))
        PROXIES = get_proxies()

    prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
    prox.http_proxy = pxy
    prox.socks_proxy = pxy
    prox.ssl_proxy = pxy

    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=co, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

    return driver



# --- YOU ONLY NEED TO CARE FROM THIS LINE ---
# creating new driver to use proxy
pd = proxy_driver(ALL_PROXIES)

# code must be in a while loop with a try to keep trying with different proxies
running = True

while running:
    try:
        mycodehere()

        # if statement to terminate loop if code working properly
        something()

        # you 
    except:
        new = ALL_PROXIES.pop()

        # reassign driver if fail to switch proxy
        pd = proxy_driver(ALL_PROXIES)
        print("--- Switched proxy to: %s" % new)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo queria escribir como comentario pero no se iba a entender:

A mi me funciona de esta manera, me gustaría darte una explicación completa, pero de esta manera te debería funcionar:

`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

```
co = Options()
co.add_argument("log-level=3")
co.add_argument("--headless")
```

Y luego crear el `driver` asi:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=co, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: Me siguen dando esta serie de errores: https://hastebin.com/ucuyakewem.sql

Comment: quizás te sirva esta solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662935/python3-cant-set-socks-proxy-with-chromedriver-socks-py-type-integer-error

Comment: Eso ya lo vi, y el problema es que solo se le puede añadir un solo proxy